# How to manage focus/cursor position with added/removed inputs in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm making a directive that should automatically create another input field when all of them are filled.  So in this example, when I stop typing in the 3rd input, a 4th will appear, but my cursor should remain in the 3rd input.

The problem is that in my code the final input is always there, so when I update the data, and move its value to the second to last input, it retains focus, and I can't focus the second to last input fast enough to prevent both the flicker and the loss of a character when the user starts typing quickly after the debounce interval ends.

How can I make this work correctly?

The XY version of this question is: how can I perform an action synchronously after ng-repeat adds a new element to the DOM?

[image: ui example]

### [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/VXY7JxjPKTT09IuUcLli?p=preview)

```js
scope: {
    // String[]
    items: '=',

    // 'input' or 'textarea'
    type: '@',

    // 'text', 'email', 'url', etc.
    inputType: '@'
},

link: function (scope, element) {
    scope._inputType = scope.inputType || 'text';
    scope.temp = {
        item: ""
    };

    var $el = jQuery(element.get(0));

    // add another input when the user stops typing in the last input
    scope.$watch('temp.item', (debounce)(function(){
        if (scope.temp.item) {
            scope.items.push(scope.temp.item);
            scope.temp.item = "";
            var elLast = $el.find('.item-last');
            elLast.blur();

            var currentInput = elLast.prev('.item-input').find('input').get(0);
            var tries = 100;

            // use nextTick to reduce time-to-update
            // this often fires a few times before angular actually updates anything
            nextTick(function again(){
                var target = elLast.prev('.item-input').find('input');

                // has angular updated?  if not: retry
                if (target.get(0) === currentInput && (--tries) > 0) {
                    return nextTick(again);
                }

                // focus and move cursor to end
                target.focus();
                var len = target.val().length;
                target.get(0).setSelectionRange(len, len);
            }, 0, false);
        }
    }, 500));

    // remove empty items after a few seconds
    scope.$watch('items', debounce(function(){
        var items = scope.items;
        var inputs = $el.find('.item-input > *');
        var emptyBeforeFocused = 0;
        var focusedIndex = null;

        for (var i=0; i<inputs.length-1; i++) {
            if (inputs.eq(i).is(':focus')) {
                focusedIndex = i;
                break;
            }
            if(!items[i]) {
                emptyBeforeFocused++;
            }
        }

        var originalLength = scope.items.length;
        scope.items = scope.items.filter(x => x.length);

        // we need to fix focus if a previous element was removed
        if (scope.items.length !== originalLength && emptyBeforeFocused > 0 && focusedIndex) {
            scope.$evalAsync(function(){
                // grab the index of the focused input, minus the preceding removed inputs
                // i.e. the input's new index
                var target = $el.find('.item-input > *').eq(focusedIndex - emptyBeforeFocused);

                // focus and move cursor to end
                target.focus();
                var val = scope.type === 'textarea' ? target.text() : target.val();
                var len = val.length;
                target.get(0).setSelectionRange(len, len);
            }, 0, false);
        }
    }, 5000));
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div ng-if="type === 'input'">
        <div class="item-input item-type-input" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
            <input type="text" ng-model="items[$index]" class="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="item-input item-type-input item-last">
            <input type="text" ng-model="temp.item" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="type === 'textarea'">
        <div class="item-input item-type-textarea" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
            <textarea ng-model="items[$index]" class="form-control" ></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="item-input item-type-textarea item-last">
            <textarea ng-model="temp.item" class="form-control" ></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve. Simply adding a new input element should not move your focus. Why are you using `.blur()` and `.focus()` ?

Comment: The problem is that when the user stops typing and temp.item is pushed to scope.items, `.item-last input` still has focus.  I updated the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yami8pKz6u96RZLBFzGC?p=preview) to very clearly show which is `.item-last input`

Comment: If you do not use any `blur()` or `focus()`, it should not automatically refocus on new items. Or do you have any other code that makes it do this specifically?

Comment: Here's an example with [all of the complexity removed](http://plnkr.co/edit/uhVd1q6JYmn8T8AEncKU?p=preview).  It doesn't behave how I want, because if you pause to think for half a second it tries to focus the other input.  Also the actual page has a lot of bindings, so it regularly causes characters to be lost due to perf problems – this isn't visible on the other plunk.  **The goal is to focus the new input synchronously after ng-repeat adds it**.  The only solution I see is not using angular templates, and just constructing the dom nodes manually.  I'm hoping there's an alternative.

Comment: Then isn't your issue more of a logical problem than a code issue? If you automatically add+focus a new input as soon as you stop typing, it will obviously also do this if you are simply stopping a second to think. If you want it to be more userfriendly in every case, you'll first need to think of how you want to do this.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have an input outside the `ng-repeat` loop?

Comment: @zeroflagL, the last input isn't part of the items array.  Its value is added to the items array when you stop typing.

Comment: In your production code, is `items` an array of strings, too, or is it an array of objects?

Comment: An array of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XN0pUN5aD0M6bhqqp0HI?p=preview)

```
.directive('resetFocus', [function(){
  return function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
    if(scope.$last){
      element.find('input').focus();
    }
  };
}])

<div class="item-input item-type-input" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" reset-focus>
    <input type="text" ng-model="items[$index]" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

Since you're also doing removal, you may need to $watch('$last')

```
.directive('resetFocus', [function(){
  return function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
    if(scope.$last){
      element.find('input').focus();
    }
    scope.$watch('$last', function(){
        if(scope.$last){
            element.find('input').focus();
        }
    });
  };
}])
```

The directive sets the focus on the last input element in the ng-repeat when it is created.  It takes advantage of the fact that ng-repeat will add $last to the scope.

Comment: This is a heck of a lot simpler, but it still suffers the same problem.  I added a hack to simulate a longer digest time, [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/y42om1SvzSDcTjxz4B9f?p=preview).  With a bit of chance a character is lost during the swap.  Accepting because it appears to be the closest I'll get to a solution (I'm going to wait a few days on the bounty, just in case though).

Comment: Lost or applied to the wrong input element?  I'm looking at your plnkr and can't quite see how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: May be browser dependent (I'm using Safari).  I slowed the digest cycle way down (1 second), and even typing pretty fast didn't lose characters.  The addition of the new input element and setting of the focus takes place on the same digest cycle (at least for the insert case), so long digest cycles shouldn't be affecting input.  I'll keep trying to reproduce.

Comment: I was testing in chrome, but for some reason I can't reproduce it today – it might have just been something weird going on.  It also works on the main site, so I think it's all good.  Thank you :-)